# Count singular post views automatically

Tags: posts, loop, hooks, actions, count

I'm trying to add some function to each loop called in the themes. What I'm doing is I add a function to count post view from here [post views without plugin](http://wp-snippets.com/post-views-without-plugin/), to use the function I need to add this line `<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>` to `single.php`, `page.php`, etc.

I want to know whether I can use some hook to automatically add the `<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>` line without hard code it for each `single.php`, `page.php` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook into `template_redirect` and execute a helper function:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_75558_count' );

function wpse_75558_count()
{
    if ( is_singular() )
        setPostViews( get_the_ID() );
}
```

To **display** the post views, you have to use a later hook. I would recommend `the_content`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_75558_show_count' );

function wpse_75558_show_count( $content )
{
    $count = getPostViews( get_the_ID() );

    if ( ! is_numeric( $count ) )
        $count = ''; // prevent errors showing to visitors
    else
        $count = "<p class='view-count'>Views: $count</p>";

    return $content . $count;
}
```

Just an idea, I haven’t tested the code.

Comment: Thanks @toscho it works like a charm :D, only there is one problem, when using with setPostViews it works okay, and value get into database, but when use for getPostViews, it show nothing, try to print_r(getPostViews()) still get nothing. Any idea?

Comment: @nackle `template_redirect` action happens too early to print something out. I made an update with a second suggestion.

Comment: thanks this is working great, btw you forgot to close the if statement, oh and I remove the if stamement since it looks like the getPostViews already handle the value to be 0 when there is no meta or post view. Thank you so much this really help me out