# How can I set cookies on my posts so that I can get view count of that post

Tags: custom-post-types, php, ajax, javascript, cookies

[image]Can anyone help with the solution?
This is my post and I have created a custom column to get view counts on my single post. I'm want to keep a track of views for every single post. I'm trying to set a cookie when a user opens a single post.
Please provide an example so that it will be easy to understand.

Comment: I don't see how a cookie would help with this at all?

Comment: Same cookies are not enough. [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75558/count-singular-post-views-automatically) question can be helpful. More similar questions can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=count+post+views)

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for the help.
Let me check.

Comment: I think the cookies part is a bit misleading. Maybe try this way https://gretathemes.com/count-post-views/ or simply use an existing contrib plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/

Comment: @leymannx don't want to use third party plugin

Comment: It's no third-party plugin. It's an official WordPress plugin.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it and thanks for the help @leymannx

Comment: @leymannx It is absolutely a 3rd-party plugin.

Comment: @JacobPeattie – Third-party, really? Why do you consider https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/ a third-party plugin?

Comment: Because it’s not developed by the WordPress team. That’s what third party means.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for the help, I have got the solution.

Comment: @leymannx thanks for the help, I have got the solution.

Comment: What solution? Consider adding an answer below to help future readers.

Comment: @JacobPeattie – Since this is a plugin hosted and infrastructure provided by WordPress I'd consider this plugin first-party. Maybe second-party in the sense of "contributed" to make a distinction. But definitely not third-party like some (premium) plugins hosted somewhere else.

Comment: I'm having one more question, I had got the post view count for a single post but when a particular user will refresh the same page I don't want to increase the count of the post again. So, how can I avoid this?

Comment: @leymmanx This is a meaningless, and inaccurate, definition that no one else would be using. It’s certainly not the definition used by the rules of this site. Consider that apps hosted in the Apple App Store are still considered 3rd-party, and games hosted in the Xbox Marketplace/PlayStation store are also considered 3rd-party. What matters is who the developer is, and that plugin is developed and supported by a third-party developer.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm having one more question, I got the post view count for a single post but when a particular user will refresh the same page I don't want to increase the count of the post again. So, how can I avoid this?

Comment: @JacobPeattie – Thanks for your insights. Let's continue this discussion over on Meta: https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4599